# how much have you grown

Tags: inversion, exclamatives

a. My God, how you have grown!

b. My God, how have you grown!

c. My God, how much you have grown!

d. My God, how much have you grown!

Which are correct and natural?

I am pretty sure (a) and (c) work. I am not sure about the other ones.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the expletive, the classic comment to a young person the speaker hasn't seen for a long time is [How you have grown!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+you+have+grown%2Chow+much+you+have+grown&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

(b) and (d) are in question form, which isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Those of my relatives that saw me infrequently sometimes said 'How did you grow so big?' and it is alleged (I don't remember) that I once said 'By letting time pass'.